# Using old version of JSON when the JSON is updated and the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have question about JSON and JavaScript. So through web page I update JSON file and then save it to the server. Then I go to the page where there must be listed the information from the JSON but it visualisates the old information of the JSON even after refreshing the page. Only when I open a new window of web browser then it list the latest JSON. I search for any cache but there is nothing and don't know where is the problem. So how to visualisate the updated JSON after refreshing page?

I am fethching the information by jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("json2.json", function(json) {
console.log(json[0]); // this will show the info it in firebug console
var count = Object.keys(json).length;
console.log(count);
for(var i=0; i<count; i++){}});
```

This is no the full code but i can't publish it all because it so long.

Comment: can you show how you are fetching JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to browser cache, since this is the same filename.

Add this before your `$.getJSON(...`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:false
});
```

;)